# Adding in-between columns, skipping and keeping some rows/columns

Tags: python, perl, csv

I am new to programming but I have started looking into both Python and Perl.

I am looking for data in two input files that are partly CSV, selecting some of them and putting into a new output file.

Maybe Python CSV or Pandas can help here, but I'm a bit stuck when it comes to skipping/keeping rows and columns.

Also, I don't have any headers for my columns.

**Input file 1:**

```
-- Some comments
KW1
'Z1' 'F' 30 26 'S'
KW2
'Z1' 30 26 1 1 5 7 /
'Z1' 30 26 2 2 6 8 /
'Z1' 29 27 4 4 12 13 /
```

**Input file 2:**

```
-- Some comments
-- Some more comments
KW1
'Z2' 'F' 40 45 'S'
KW2
'Z2' 40 45 1 1 10 10 /
'Z2' 41 45 2 2 14 15 /
'Z2' 41 46 4 4 16 17 /
```

**Desired output file:**

```
KW_NEW
'Z_NEW' 1000 30 26 1 /
'Z_NEW' 1000 30 26 2 /
'Z_NEW' 1000 29 27 4 /
'Z_NEW' 1000 40 45 1 /
'Z_NEW' 1000 41 45 2 /
'Z_NEW' 1000 41 46 4 /
```

So what I want to do is:

- Do not include anything in either of my two input files before I reach `KW2`
- Replace `KW2` with `KW_NEW`
- Replace either `Z1' or`Z2`with`Z_NEW` in the first column
- Add a new second column with a constant value e.g. 1000
- Copy the next three columns as they are
- Leave out any remaining columns before printing the slash `/` at the end

Could anyone give me at least some general hints/tips how to approach this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# initialize output array
my @output = ('KW_NEW');

# proceed first file
open my $fh1, '<', 'in1.txt' or die "unable to open file1: $!";
while(<$fh1>) {
    # consider only lines after KW2
    if (/KW2/ .. eof) {
        # Don't treat KW2 line
        next if /KW2/;
        # split the current line on space and keep only the fifth first element
        my @l = (split ' ', $_)[0..4];
        # change the first element
        $l[0] = 'Z_NEW';
        # insert 1000 at second position
        splice @l,1,0,1000;
        # push into output array
        push @output, "@l";
    }
}

# proceed second file
open my $fh2, '<', 'in2.txt' or die "unable to open file2: $!";
while(<$fh2>) {
    if (/KW2/ .. eof) {
        next if /KW2/;
        my @l = (split ' ', $_)[0..4];
        $l[0] = 'Z_NEW';
        splice @l,1,0,1000;
        push @output, "@l";
    }
}

# write array to output file
open my $fh3, '>', 'out.txt' or die "unable to open file3: $!";
print $fh3 $_,"\n" for @output;
```

Comment: I also think it is more Perlish to use an *exclusion* `next unless /KW2/ .. eof` rather than your *inclusion* which requires its own block that terminates at the same point as the `while` loop itself. And you have a lot of code that is unnecessarily duplicated

Comment: This is really close to working for me :) The only issue I discovered is that my input file have some commented lines that I want to remove. The first comment line is right below the 'KW2' line, so that I just solved by adding another 'next if /--/;'. But the last comment line is after the last line I want to keep, how can I refer to that line (also starting with '--' and remove it from the output array? (I don't know the length of my array, so if I can't use text search to find it I need to calculate the # rows first.

Answer (score 1):

Your files are not "partly csv" (there is not a comma in sight); they are (partly) *space* delimited. You can read the files line-by-line, use Python's `.split()` method to convert the relevant strings into lists of substrings, and then re-arrange the pieces as you please. The splitting and re-assembly might look something like this:

```python
input_line = "'Z1' 30 26 1 1 5 7 /"  # test data
input_items = input_line.split()
output_items = ["'Z_NEW'", '1000']
output_items.append(input_items[1])
output_items.append(input_items[2])
output_items.append(input_items[3])
output_items.append('/')
output_line = ' '.join(output_items)
print(output_line)
```

The final `print()` statement shows that the resulting string is

```
'Z_NEW' 1000 30 26 1 /
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your file format static? (this is not actually csv by the way :P) You might want to investigate a standardized file format like JSON or strict CSV to store your data, so that you can use already-existing tools to parse your input files. python has great JSON and CSV libraries that can do all the hard stuff for you.

If you're stuck with this file format, I would try something along these lines.

```
path = '<input_path>'
kws = ['KW1', 'KW2']
desired_kw = kws[1]

def parse_columns(line):
    array = line.split()
    if array[-1] is '/':
        # get rid of trailing slash
        array = array[:-1]

def is_kw(cols):
    if len(cols) > 0 and cols[0] in kws:
        return cols[0]

# to parse the section denoted by desired keyword
with open(path, 'r') as input_fp:
    matrix = []
    reading_file = False
    for line in input_fp.readlines:
        cols = parse_columns(line)
        line_is_kw = is_kw(line)
        if line_is_kw:
            if not reading_file:
                if line_is_kw is desired_kw:
                    reading_file = True
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                break

        if reading_file:
            matrix = cols

print matrix
```

From there you can use stuff like slice notation and basic list manipulation to get your desired array. Good luck!